# How to get the correct label of an attribute on multistore

Tags: multistore, attribute-set, frontend-label

I have a piece of coding which works fine for the default store.
Now I created a multistore but this piece of coding is retrieving the default label name, but I want the labelname wich belongs to an other store.
this is the coding:

```
<label class="label"><span><?php echo $attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel(); ?></span></label>
```

and that comes from:

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */ ?>
                    <div class="field ">
                        <label class="label"><span><?php echo $attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel(); ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <select class="option-select color" name="<?php echo $block->getRealAttributeCode($attribute); ?>" id="select-<?php echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); ?>">
                                <?php foreach($block->getOptions($attribute) as $key => $value) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So how can I retreive "getDefaultFrontendLabel" from an other store??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have checked your requirement. You should use like below.

```
Use getStoreLabel() ,instead of getFrontendLabel() or getDefaultFrontendLabel()
```

Please use like above and let me know if you have any query.